Create programatically iCalendar file so expanding section "Join Zoom Meeting" appears
everyone. In Google Calendar if zoom meeting is created in the event then expandable section "Join Zoom Meeting" with ID and passcode appears. What ical properties and values of ics files are responsible for creating that "Join Zoom Meeting" section? Google Calendar event
I work on api that sends emails with ics attachments and I need to pragmatically construct such an ics that creates event with "Join Zoom Meeting" section (when user receives email). I examine ics file of manually created event and it seems that Description property carries a lot of data, not all of it is displayed in event card, but when I try to use this Description in api desired section does not show up. How to make that "Join Zoom Meeting" section appear?
Example of ics file of manually created event:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Jerusalem
X-LIC-LOCATION:Asia/Jerusalem
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0300
TZNAME:IDT
DTSTART:19700327T020000
RDATE:19700327T020000
RDATE:19710326T020000
RDATE:19720324T020000
RDATE:19730323T020000
RDATE:19740329T020000
RDATE:19750328T020000
RDATE:19760326T020000
RDATE:19770325T020000
RDATE:19780324T020000
RDATE:19790323T020000
RDATE:19800328T020000
RDATE:19810327T020000
RDATE:19820326T020000
RDATE:19830325T020000
RDATE:19840323T020000
RDATE:19850329T020000
RDATE:19860328T020000
RDATE:19870327T020000
RDATE:19880325T020000
RDATE:19890324T020000
RDATE:19900323T020000
RDATE:19910329T020000
RDATE:19920327T020000
RDATE:19930326T020000
RDATE:19940325T020000
RDATE:19950324T020000
RDATE:19960329T020000
RDATE:19970328T020000
RDATE:19980327T020000
RDATE:19990326T020000
RDATE:20000324T020000
RDATE:20010323T020000
RDATE:20020329T020000
RDATE:20030328T020000
RDATE:20040326T020000
RDATE:20050325T020000
RDATE:20060324T020000
RDATE:20070323T020000
RDATE:20080328T020000
RDATE:20090327T020000
RDATE:20100326T020000
RDATE:20110325T020000
RDATE:20120323T020000
RDATE:20130329T020000
RDATE:20140328T020000
RDATE:20150327T020000
RDATE:20160325T020000
RDATE:20170324T020000
RDATE:20180323T020000
RDATE:20190329T020000
RDATE:20200327T020000
RDATE:20210326T020000
RDATE:20220325T020000
RDATE:20230324T020000
RDATE:20240329T020000
RDATE:20250328T020000
RDATE:20260327T020000
RDATE:20270326T020000
RDATE:20280324T020000
RDATE:20290323T020000
RDATE:20300329T020000
RDATE:20310328T020000
RDATE:20320326T020000
RDATE:20330325T020000
RDATE:20340324T020000
RDATE:20350323T020000
RDATE:20360328T020000
RDATE:20370327T020000
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0300
TZNAME:IDT
DTSTART:20380326T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=4FR
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0300
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:IST
DTSTART:19701025T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Jerusalem:20240424T133000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Jerusalem:20240424T143000
DTSTAMP:20240424T110056Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Name:mailto:email@example.com
UID:123s403r3rap2342343243243@google.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=
 TRUE;CN=email2@example.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:email2@example.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE
 ;CN=Name;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:email2@example.com
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:1906658865
CREATED:20240424T110053Z
DESCRIPTION:<p><br>──────────<br><br>https://us05web.zoom.us/j/12121212121?
 pwd=wszHbnmi964jzr1FNN2iWLBSXLP111.1<br><br><a href="https://applications.z
 oom.us/addon/invitation/detail?meetingUuid=Jnmbgh4%2FSb6xXMu4N%2BsxVg%3D%3D
 &signature=879500113e244cea5a3dea87cf0a50d52cebf2a5ab6aa8f2215b60eccd6142ae
 &v=1" target="_blank">Joining Instructions</a><br><br>──────────</p>\n\n-::
 ~:~::~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:
 ~::~:~::-\nJoin Zoom Meeting\nhttps://us05web.zoom.us/j/12121212121?pwd=wszHbnmi96
4jzr1FNN2iWLBSXLP111.1 (ID: 12121212121\, passcode: PassCode)\n\nJoini
 ng instructions: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://applications.zoom.us/
 addon/invitation/detail?meetingUuid%3DDjYPuA4%252FSb6xXMu4N%252BsxVg%253D%2
 53D%26signature%3D879500113e244cea5a3dea87cf0a50d52cebf2a5ab6aa8f2215b60ecc
 d6142ae%26v%3D1&sa=D&source=calendar&usg=AOvVaw0EiDmso0BQG2hk_wEgntnh\n\n--
 ----------<br /><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://support.zoom.
 us/hc/en-us/articles/360020187492-Zoom-for-GSuite-add-on-Troubleshooting%23
 h_01FRGZTWJYRGRDMPQW4N041QF7&amp\;sa=D&amp\;source=calendar&amp\;usg=AOvVaw
 3pOlmJKYg-DG37_G4Qn9Q2" target="_blank">Zoom for G Suite Add-On Help</a><br
  />------------<br /><br />Meeting host: <a href="mailto:email2@example.com" t
 arget="_blank">email2@example.com</a><br /><br />Join Zoom Meeting: <br /><a h
 ref="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://us05web.zoom.us/j/12121212121?pwd
 %wszHbnmi96m4jzr1FNN2iWLBSXLP111.1&amp\;sa=D&amp\;source=calendar&amp\;usg
 =AOvVaw2plDwZ1_B7VWPZlgawLiUe" target="_blank">https://us05web.zoom.us/j/12
 12121212121?pwd=wszHbnmi96jzr1FNN2iWLBSXLP4iM.1</a>\n\nPlease do not edit th
 is section.\n-::~:~::~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:
 ~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~::~:~::-
LAST-MODIFIED:20240424T110053Z
LOCATION:https://us05web.zoom.us/j/12121212121?pwd=wszHbnmi964jzr1FNN2iWLBS
 XLP4iM.1
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Test event #2
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR


Did you try sending yourself an invitation and looking at it?

@rand'Chris, yes, I tried. I expected to see custom Google Properties like X-GOOGLE- which would be responsible for creating that section, but they are absent. What is present is X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID with some number which may or may not be ID of zoom data saved at google site (just a hypothesis, don't  know how to verify it of sure). There is a LOCATION property which places zoom link at location in the event card but does not create Join Zoom Meeting" section. DESCRIPTION property hols a lot of data. But when I take it to try at api it is just ignored.

I see you asking on the Google Support forum as well. It looks like you need to engage your debugging skills. If you have an ICS that you can import and it does what you need you're good to start. Delete 1/2 the text and import that. If it still does what you want, it's something in the remaining text. Keep removing stuff until you find the line that makes it stop. Note that there may be several lines needed to make it show up. When you figure it out, post it as an answer and accept it so others can benefit. Looking at your post, I'd guess it's either LOCATION or it's parsing the DESCRIPTION.

Before I asked this question I was doing that, no use. LOCATION creates zoom link near "location" icon but neither whole DESCRIPTION, nor any part of it creates that zoom section. As I was told at Google forum this might be possible only using Google Calendar API.

Ok, so I'm confused. You should put your relevant testing in the question, and remove unnecessary speculation. I thought I understood that you could download an event as an ICS, delete the event from the calendar (for instance), and then import the ICS and it did what you wanted. Is that the case or not?
